# Pbl xcode C++ typedef struct toto toto

Tags: xcode, macos, struct, g++, typedef

I am working on a C++ project on macOS X 10.6.2 with xcode.

I tried to compile my code on windows and do not have any problem, I guess Linux is working but I don't have one with me right now.

My problem is xcode do not accept this kind of instruction :

```
struct direction {
double x;
double y;
double z;
double t; };

typedef struct direction direction;
```

Here is my error :

> /Users/sbarbier/dev/xcode/Infographie/TP9-RayTracing/RayTracing-Direction.h:22:0     /Users/sbarbier/dev/xcode/Infographie/TP9-RayTracing/RayTracing-Direction.h:22: error: changes meaning of 'direction' from 'typedef struct direction direction'

I am using GCC4.2 and haven't change anything. This code works on every platform, can any one help me ?

Comment: I just tried and looks like it works on Linux

Answer (score 0):

This isn't C. In C, to use a `struct` you had to use the keyword `struct`:

```
struct some_struct{ int i; };
struct some_struct myStruct;
```

This was alleviated like this, commonly:

```
typedef struct { int i; } some_struct;
some_struct myStruct;
```

In C++ this is not required. `direction` already has a type, then you're trying to make a new type of the same name, and that's bad. Take out your entire `typedef`, it isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `struct` and `class` are used only when declaring or defining the struct or class.  You might want the typedef in C, but in C++ it doesn't make any sense.